# Send SMS using text from random row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ifttt

Is it possible to, saying a keyword or phrase to Google assistant, trigger an SMS to be sent to someone whose text is a random cell from a Google sheet?

Comment: Sure, but you'll need to write a custom IFTTT service to do it.

Comment: @Sneftel cool. I had a go but I can't see how to!

Comment: In fact, I can't see any way of using cells from google sheets as ingredients - that would be enough, I think!